# Compare one to one lines in 2 different files using shell scripting

Tags: bash, files, diff, cut

I have two files:

```
File1         File2

abc           abc
cde           cde,xyz,efg,hij,...,n

efg           lmn,opq,weq,...n
```

Now I want to compare *File1 line1* with *File2 line1*, *line2* with *line2* and so on. However, in File2 a single line can have multiple entries separated with 'comma'.

Now if the entry in *File1* matches with any of the corresponding line entries in *File2* the result should be OK, else show the difference.

For example:

```
File1         File2

cde           cde,xyz,efg,hij,opt
```

the result should be OK because `cde` exist in both files.

Can you please help me out to write a shell script like diff gave me, including the entry differences.

Comment: Does file1 always only have one field?

Comment: No effort from the OP, just asking for complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very pretty perhaps but something like this could be a start:

```
# 1. Read lines from file1 as string, and file2 as comma-separated array.
while read -r a && IFS=, read -ra b <&3; do
    # 2. If both empty lines, continue.
    if [[ "$a" == "" && ${#b[@]} == 0 ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    # 3. Start assuming diff.
    diff=1
    # 4. Loop fields in $b.
    for e in ${b[@]}; do
        # Compare field in $b with $a, if match then abort.
        if [[ "$e" == "$a" ]]; then
            diff=0
            break
        fi
    done
    # 5. If no match found, print line from $b.
    if [[ $diff == 1 ]]; then
        # Join array with <space>comma.
        line=$(printf ", %s" "${b[@]}")
        # Print line, excluding leading <space>comma.
        printf "%s\n" "${line:2}"
    fi
# Input argument one as file 1 to stdin, and argument two as file 2 to
# file descriptor 3.
done < "$1" 3<"$2"
```

Typically used as:

```
$ ./myscript file1 file2
```

Now using something like Python, Perl, awk etc. or would likely be better.

Comment: Thank you. But there is a problem for the same. if 1 file has efg and other has efghi,abc,def... it gives a exact match.. How can  i check that

Comment: @KaranKohli: Do I read you correctly if you are saying you want file1:`efg` to match file2:`efghi` ?

Comment: @KaranKohli: And, if so, do you also want file1:`efghi` to match file2:`efg`? And what about sub-matches? Should file1:`efg` and file2:`xxefgxx` or file1:`efg` and file2:`xxefg` also result in OK (skip/no diff)?

Comment: @KaranKohli: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this stack overflow answers put you in the right direction:

1. [Looping through the content of a file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462/1816774)
2. [String contains in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/1816774)

Most probably you want to put each line of each file in a [loop list](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html) or [array](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html), using the first suggestion. Then iterate over both of them simultaneous and compare the strings using the second suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Tim. However, I already tried the above 2 links. I always get stuck in comparing the exact lines if in multiple loop

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
paste file1 file2 | grep -vP '^(.*)\t.*\1.*'
```

and possibly adapt the regex to your case.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk you can do it in one line:

```
awk '{a=$0;getline <File2;if($0 ~ a)print "OK"; else print a,$0}' File1
```